# .htaccess on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm not sure about the location that my .htaccess should be. I'm working on a WordPress theme. Is it ok to leave it inside the theme's folder? Or should I overwrite the original WordPress .htaccess on the root folder?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always have the .htaccess file in the root directory of your wordpress files not inside of the theme.

Comment: Yes, I just need to wait some minutes before it lets me accept it.